# Undoing git remove

Tags: git

I've accidentally executed the following command:

```
git rm -r .
```

Not surprisingly, it removed everything.  Is there any way to revert it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
git reset HEAD
```

If you don't have any uncommitted changes that you care about, then

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

should forcibly reset everything to your last commit. If you do have uncommitted changes, but the first command doesn't work, then save your uncommitted changes with git stash:

```
git stash
git reset --hard HEAD
git stash pop
```

To restore all the deleted files in a folder enter the following command.

```
 git ls-files -d | xargs git checkout --
```

to check what got deleted try:

```
git-ls-files --deleted
```